# How would a native speaker react to the proverbial phrase: "Life is lethal"?

Tags: translation, proverbs, humor, german

Would it sound completely wrong?

Would it be understood humoristically?

Would "deadly" be better?

It's an attempt to translate the humoristic German sentence:

> *Das Leben ist tödlich.*

I often use it as a reply to for example people expressing their fear of statistically unlikely events such as being involved in a plane crash or the like. But can it even be translated to still be kind of funny?

Comment: How ’bout “brutal”?   ’lethal’ sounds dumb to me.

Comment: "On a long enough timeline, the survival rate for everyone drops to zero."

Comment: No one gets out of here alive. It’s a cultural reference that most native English speakers will have heard https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_One_Here_Gets_Out_Alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to ask about a translation, or if it would be appropriate in English, because there are several variations of this proverb already in existence in English, one of which dates all the way back to 1656.

From [the Quote Investigator](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/01/29/life/):

> > Life is a sexually transmitted terminal disease.
>
> Would you please explore its provenance?
>
> **Quote Investigator**: Tracing this statement is difficult because it emerged from a family of related sayings. Here is a summary snapshot showing quotations with dates:
>
> > 1656: Life is an Incurable Disease. —Abraham Cowley
> > 1943: Some people think of life as a fatal disease. —Francis T. Cunningham
> > 1968: Life is a hereditary disease. —Anonymous Graffito
> > 1971: Life is a terminal disease. —Anonymous Graffito
> > 1980: Life is a sexually transmitted disease. —Anonymous Graffito
> > 1981: Life is just another sexually transmitted social disease. —Margaret Atwood
> > 1982: Life is a sexually transmitted disease. — attributed to Posy Simmonds
> > 1982: Life is a sexually transmitted disease. —Guy Bellamy
> > 1984: Life is a sexually transmitted terminal disease. —Marilyn Duckworth
> > 1985: Life is a sexually transmitted disease & there’s a 100% mortality rate. —R. D. Laing

In 1997, Paula Gunn Allen published ["Life Is a Fatal Disease: Selected Poems, 1962-1995."](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0931122856)

In 2004, Lis Harvey released the song ["Life Is Fatal."](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00149KZ74)

In 2009, Zeke Hoskin released the song ["Life Is Lethal."](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0026EVQ5Q)

So, this saying, and its variations, have been part of English culture for a while now.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!